# TextToSpeech (TTS)

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i am making an application that reads sentences when clicking them, so i used the TTS to read them.
the problem is that the voice is not that clear, so is there a way to change it?or make it read slower?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use function `setSpeechRate` to make voice faster.

1.0 is the normal speech rate, lower values slow down the speech (0.5 is half the normal speech rate), greater values accelerate it (2.0 is twice the normal speech rate).

Comment: @user1283769 even after setting setSpeechRate it didn't work for me.. Would it be possible for you to post the entire code?? Do I need to set any engine?